# enumerate ruby variable in single line of code

Tags: ruby

This is a bit odd perhaps, but wondering if it is possible to achieve the following in a ***single*** line of Ruby code.

```
bar = 15
foo = 5
10.times { foo = foo + 1 }
puts foo == bar
```

i.e. I want to perform an action on a predefined variable a number of times, then compare it to another variable, returning a boolean based on whether they are equal, but in a single line of code?

Comment: You are not changing `answer_should_be`, aren't you? And then you check whether it changed or not. Something strange is going here.

Comment: Sorry, example code was nonsense! Thanks for pointing that out, now fixed, I hope.

Comment: In your real code you need that for `Fixnum`s as in example or for some mutable objects like strings or arrays? Btw, you `single line` is quite dangerous restriction: you can write you example in a single line separating statements with semi-colons =)

Comment: strings, very good point about the semi-colons - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce) will help.

```
puts (0..9).reduce(5) { |acc, _| acc + 1 } == 15
```

The number of iteration is passed as the object whose `reduce` is being called. The initial value is passed as `reduce`'s argument. The action is performed in the block and the result of each execution is carried through iterations as the first argument of the block.

The only thing missing are assignments to variables. Let's do it.

```
puts (foo = (0..9).reduce(5) { |acc, _| acc + 1 }) == bar = 15
```

So yes, it *is* possible, however I'd recommend a verbose, multiline and *readable* solution.

Comment: Alternative way :) Array.new(10, 1).inject(5) { |sum, el| sum + el } == 15

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this, and yes, I appreciate that readable is best, will try and re-factor nicely, just wanted to see if it could be done :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 puts((foo, bar = 5, 15; 10.times { foo += 1 }; foo) == bar)
```